# RN Gesture handler and Flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-gesture-handler

I have wrapped  inside  and I want the pan gesture to take over when Flatlist has reached the top. Something similar to Spotify’s Music Player when it is expanded in full screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: No @KingAmo I haven’t